# Which is the better way to store users and companies when designing an online b2b app?

Tags: database-design, architecture

I'm designing an online app which allows users to sign into the app and create projects. Now we need to add companies, so that users can belong to their own companies and have team members join their company and collaborate on projects.

As far as I can see there are two different ways to do this:

1. Expand the current Users table so that every user can potentially be a company. Other users would join on to an existing company user in a parent / child relationship. Each of the users in the system *could* either be a fully fledged company, or just a subordinate team member with reduced powers. Projects are owned by the main user who is the company. The main user can never be removed without closing the company as well, they are one in the same thing. The Users table now has a mixture of company users and team member users.
2. Keep the current Users table and add a second Companies table. Each user would no longer own their own projects, the company would own all projects while the users just act on behalf of the company. Each user doesnt need to store anything beyond their login details, which company they belong to and what their privilege level is. Companies on the other hand, store all projects, team members and clients. This will require a bit of refactoring of the code however.

To my mind, No. 2 is clearly the better way to go about it, pretty much a no-brainer. Am I correct, or is there anything I've missed?

TL;DR: Users and Companies in one table, or split Users and Companies into two different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2, definitely. I don't think there's anything you've missed. Have you read option 1 back to yourself a few times? It sounds like a complete nightmare.

> The main user can never be removed without closing the company as well, they are one in the same thing.

This sentence in particular dooms option 1 by itself.

I would do a little code refactoring if it means going with the simpler, more flexible database design of option 2.